# How to find the derivative of $g(x)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

I want to find this derivative, but I don't know what to do with the term $(x-t)^2$:

Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Define $g:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ as follows:
\begin{equation}
g(x)=\int_0^{x}{(x-t)^2\cdot f(t)}\,dt
\end{equation}

Find $g(x)'''$.

Comment: Use the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I don't know what to do with $(x-t)^2$.

Comment: You can expand $(x-t)^2$ and break up $g$ in three integrals on which you can apply the FTOC (together with the product rule). Alternatively see [differentiation under the integral sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign).

Comment: Use the chain rule.

Comment: Thank you Git Gud, I'm looking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any constant $a$,
$$
\int_{a}^{x} h(x,t) f(t) dt = h(x,x)f(x) + \int_{a}^{x} \frac{d}{dx}(h(x,t))\cdot f(t) dt 
$$
Using this three times, with $A=0$ and  $h(x,t) = (x-t)^2$, and using $x-x = 0$ twice, we have:
$$
g(x) =  \int_{0}^{x} (x-t)^2 f(t) dt
$$
$$
g^{\prime}(x) =  \int_{0}^{x} 2(x-t) f(t) dt
$$
$$
g^{\prime\prime}(x) =  2 \int_{0}^{x} f(t) dt
$$
$$
g^{\prime\prime\prime}(x) =  2  f(x) 
$$
which is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have an intermediate function of two variables, namely
$$G(u,v):=\int_0^u(v-t)^2\ f(t)\ dt\ ,$$
and want to know the third derivative of the function
$$g(x):=G(x,x)\ ,$$
implying $u(x)=x$, $\>v(x)=x$. Using the chain rule we obtain
$$g'(x)=G_u(x,x)\cdot 1+G_v(x,x)\cdot 1=(x-x)^2 f(x)+\int_0^x2(x-t)\ f(t)\ dt\ .$$
Proceeding in a similar way we obtain
$$g''(x)=2(x-x)f(x)+\int_0^x 2f(t)\ dt\ ,$$
so that in the end we have
$$g'''(x)=2f(x)\ .$$